# Can C++ enable_if have a default implementation?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write a function `print` which behaves differently according to the type of its argument.

Here is my implementation:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_array<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void print(const T &v) {
  std::cout << "array: ";
  for (const auto &e : v) {
    std::cout << e << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void print(const T &v) {
  std::cout << "integral: " << v << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<!(std::is_array<T>::value || std::is_integral<T>::value), int>::type = 0>
void print(const T &v) {
  std::cout << "default: " << v << std::endl;
}
```

This code works as expected, but the conditions in the last specification are too complicated.

Is there any solution to simplify the last one?

Comment: Not sure what you would consider simpler.  Shorter?

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes. When there are lots of cases, the condition clause of the default one may be very long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A general approach you can use for a default case is to have a function which takes a variable argument list.  This will only be used if no other function matches.  Here is an example:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_array<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void print_helper(const T &v,int) {
  std::cout << "array: ";
  for (const auto &e : v) {
    std::cout << e << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void print_helper(const T &v,int) {
  std::cout << "integral: " << v << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void print_helper(const T &v,...) {
  std::cout << "default: " << v << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void print(const T &v)
{
  print_helper(v,0);
}
```

For only two overloads, the extra function may not be worth it, but as you get more overloads this form can really pay off for the default case.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good workaround, but any other more beautiful solutions?

Answer (score 1):

We can use an extra chooser to make things better for us, courtesy of [Xeo](https://rmf.io/cxx11/overload-ranking/):

```
struct otherwise{ otherwise(...){} };

template<unsigned I>
struct choice : choice<I+1>{};

// terminate recursive inheritence at a convenient point,
// large enough to cover all cases
template<> struct choice<10>{};
```

Then each ranking on our choice list will be preferred to the next, and we just have to disable as we go:

```
// just forward to our first choice
template <class T> void print(const T &v) { print(v, choice<0>{}); }
```

Where our top choice is array:

```
template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_array<T>::value>>
void print(const T& v, choice<0> ) { ... }
```

And then integral:

```
template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
void print(const T& v, choice<1> ) { ... }
```

And then anything

```
template <class T>
void print(const T& v, otherwise ) { ... }
```

This structure allows for arbitrarily many choices.